# OpenGL compute shader: Why can't I bind more than 16 SSBOs?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, linker-errors, compute-shader

I'm on my 17th SSBO declaration in my compute shader, and I am receiving a link-time error,

```
C5058: no buffers available for bindable storage buffer
```

I'm on a GTX 1070, with GL_MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_BINDINGS = 96, and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't letting me declare and bind more than 16 SSBOs. I've looked for whether or not I need an extension, but can't seem to find anything except an old, unanswered, seemingly unrelated thread about QT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm on a GTX 1070, with `GL_MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_BINDINGS` = 96,
> and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't letting me declare and
> bind more than 16 SSBOs.

Because that is not the correct limit. `GL_MAX_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_BINDINGS` is just the limit on the total number of different SSBOs you can have bound at the same time in your OpenGL state, but there are limits on the actual number of SSBO blocks which can be accessed *per shader stage* (using the minimum values from the current GL 4.6 spec here):

- `MAX_VERTEX_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCKS`, guaranteed minimum: 0
- `MAX_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCKS`, guaranteed minimum: 0
- `MAX_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCKS`, guaranteed minimum: 0
- `MAX_GEOMETRY_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCKS`, guaranteed minimum: 0
- `MAX_FRAGMENT_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCKS`, guaranteed minimum: 8
- `MAX_COMPUTE_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCKS`, guaranteed minimum: 8

So by using more than 8 SSBOs in your compute shader, you are already outside of what a conforming GL 4.6 implementation is required to provide, and with more than 16, you are out of what your particular GL implementation does provide, as NVIDIA's current driverers seem to support 16 SSBOs per statge, and they allow you to keep that many different SSBOs bound at a single time (6*16=96).

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know of any resources for seeing the limits over a distribution of cards? I'm working on a game, and 8 buffers is way too few for what this shader is doing. I'm going to only barely skate by with taking one out to bring me back down to 16, so I'm wondering if there's a way to tell how unique or common it is to allow 16.

Comment: @gdevi https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displaycapability.php?name=GL_MAX_COMPUTE_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCKS

Comment: @gdevi Surely you can figure out a way to combine some of them together.

Comment: @user253751 Well sure, it's all the same at some point, right? I could reduce some of my ivecN arrays to just ints, push them all together into a single int[], and pass in uniforms for the individual offsets+lengths. It all just seemed like needless complication, I'm just not familiar enough with GPU hardware architecture to understand why a limit on buffer binding locations would even exist, let alone be so low.